# ADF / Synapse Pipeline Expression get Substring from a Split function

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, expressionbuilder

I am trying to get year month value from file name by using the split and substring function together, for example: "SampleFile_202307.csv". I tried getting the month value by using the Set variable activity, and set a pipeline variable v_test to this value:

```
@substring(split('SampleFile_202307.csv','_')[1], 4, 2)
```

But I am getting this error with the split function "Cannot fit unknown into the function parameter string. (6)"

> split('SampleFile_202307.csv','_')[1],

Please help me fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? I also got same error in dynamic expression but still it manages to debug and gave me output as month value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
@substring(split('SampleFile_202307.csv','_')[1], 4, 2)
```

As in above dynamic expression **substring function expects String** value as a first parameter but we are passing `split` function because of this it is showing this **warning in dynamic expression only when debugging it manages to debug and gave me output**.

You can use two set variables to perform this First will split the sting `@split('SampleFile_202307.csv','_')[1]` and second will get substring from string `@substring(variables('year'), 4, 2)`.

***But when I am debugging it manages to debug and gave me output as month value.***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yes when I debug it, it did give me the output, also, thank you for the suggestion on breaking it into two set variables.